# Friend claims $\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n^s+x^\phi)^{\phi}}dx=\zeta(s)$

Tags: integration

$\phi=\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$, the golden ratio.

$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^s}$ is the Zeta function valid for Re(s)>1

Where $ n \ge 1$

$$\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n^s+x^\phi)^{\phi}}dx=\zeta(s)$$

My dear friend claims that this is true and I told him that here a maths site that can help answer these sort of questions. Is my friend joking with me? It is his integral above correct? Can anyone please answer it?

Comment: Did he only claim this to be true, or did he actually calculate the left side ?

Comment: He just make a claim and told me to verify it, left me puzzle for a while

Comment: I checked some values with PARI/GP numerically, and the claim COULD be true. However, I have no idea how to verify it. Because of the good fitness for relatively large $s$ (Say $5$ or $6$), it can be ruled out that your friend just produced a random formula as a joke. It has to be taken serious.

Comment: @Peter (+1). So he wasn't joking with me after all. How can zeta function link with golden ratio?

Comment: No idea, but there should be suitable substitutions for the integral ...

Comment: Another possibility. He knows another representation for $\zeta(s)$, that has something to do with $\phi$. Look at wikipedia or mathworld, maybe you find something interesting.

Comment: I have see $\phi$ with $\pi$ And other but not with zeta. maybe there is another representation with $\phi$

Comment: @pisquare, See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18589/golden-number-theory/24553#24553), there is the golden ratio involved.

Comment: You want to prove that $$I(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac1{(a+x^\phi)^\phi}dx=\frac1{a}.$$ 
The substitution $\large x \mapsto x \,a^{\frac1{\phi}}$ 
 shows that you only need to calculate $I(1)$, which was done in more than one way here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1328423/how-to-compute-int-0-infty-frac11x-varphi-varphi-dx

Comment: Bravo @nospoon, it just then take the sum and we arrive at the zeta function